# javascript to reference input IDs in php loop and pass values back to same input ID

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, loops

I have a form which is essentially an autocomplete input box. I can get this to work perfectly for a single text box. What I need to do is create unique input boxes by using a php for loop. This will use the counter $i to give each input box a unique name and id.

The problem is that the unique value of the input box needs to be passed to the javascript. this will then pass the inputted data to the external php page and return the mysql results.

As mentioned I have this working for a single input box but need assistance with passing the correct values to the javascript and returning it to correct input box.

**existing code for working solution (first row works only, all other rows update first row input box)**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("autocompleteperson.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="addepartment.php" method="post">
<table>
<?  for ( $i = 1; $i <=10; $i++ ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <? echo  $i; ?></td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
            </div>
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 20px;" alt="upArrow" />
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            </div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
<?  }   ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**code for autocompleteperson.php is:**

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT fullname FROM Persons WHERE fullname LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
if($query) {
    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->fullname.'\');">'.$result->fullname.'</li>';
    }
}
```

in order to get it to work for all rows, I include the counter $i in each of the file names as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(inputString<? echo  $i; ?>) {
        if(inputString<? echo  $i; ?>.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions<? echo  $i; ?>').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("autocompleteperson.php", {queryString: ""+inputString<? echo  $i; ?>+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions<? echo  $i; ?>').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList<? echo  $i; ?>').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputString<? echo  $i; ?>').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions<? echo  $i; ?>').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="addepartment.php" method="post">
<table>
<?  for ( $i = 1; $i <=10; $i++ ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <? echo  $i; ?></td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString<? echo  $i; ?>" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
            </div>
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions<? echo  $i; ?>" style="display: none;">
                <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 20px;" alt="upArrow" />
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList<? echo  $i; ?>">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            </div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
<?  }   ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The autocomplete suggestion works (although always shown on first row) but when selecting the data always returns to row 1, even if input was on row 5. I have a feeling this has to do with the fill()  but not sure? is it due the the autocomplete page code? or does the fill referencing ThisValue have something to do with it.

example of this page (as above) can be found [here](http://www.shedatabase.co.za/versionfour/configdept2.php)

Thanks for the assistance, much appreciated.

**UPDATE - LOLO**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(i, inputString) {
        if(inputValue.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions' + i).hide();
        } else {
            $.post("autocompleteperson.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions' + i).show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList' + i).html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup

    function fill(i, thisValue) {
        $('#inputString' + i).val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions' + i).hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="addepartment.php" method="post">
<table>
<?  for ( $i = 1; $i <=10; $i++ ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <? echo  $i; ?></td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString<?php echo $i; ?>" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
            </div>
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions<? echo  $i; ?>" style="display: none;">
                <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 20px;" alt="upArrow" />
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList<? echo  $i; ?>">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            </div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
<?  }   ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

google chrome catched the following errors:

first line on input, second line on loosing focus
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix JS with PHP. PHP is a server-side language, you can render dynamic JS with that, but after it's rendered you cannot use PHP with JS. First of all you should change your JS functions, I suggest to add parameter like `i` which will contain input number:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(i, inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions' + i).hide();
        } else {
            $.post("autocompleteperson.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions' + i).show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList' + i).html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup

    function fill(i, thisValue) {
        $('#inputString' + i).val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions" + i + "').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
```

Then change invokation of this functions and provide number:

```
<input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString<? echo  $i; ?>" onkeyup="lookup(<? echo $i; ?>, this.value);" onblur="fill(<? echo $i; ?>);" />
```

That should be enough.

Comment: Thanks @Lolo, made the changes as you suggested. provided updated code at bottom of question. No autocomplete is suggested now when user provides input? is i being passed correctly to lookup(i,inputstring)? Thanks again.

Comment: As is can see from your updated question, you haven't changed invokations in `<input>` tag. Try changing event handlers to `onkeyup="lookup(<? echo $i; ?>, this.value);" onblur="fill(<? echo $i; ?>);"`

Comment: Thanks Lolo. I have made the changes and again updated the questions with my current code. It is still not displaying any data when updating the input box content? example is http://www.shedatabase.co.za/versionfour/configdept2.php

Comment: Hi Lolo, google chrome does display some errors as shown at bottom of question: " Uncaught ReferenceError: inputValue is not defined " and " Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined " Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Lolo, progress. autocomplete appears perfectly but doesnt allow the selected value to be displayed in input box. selection disappears without value being updated. see link above to view. Thanks as always, really apprecaited.

Comment: Selection doesn't work because you send data from php with onclick event handler which is incorrect. Try to remove onclick handlers from <li> elements in php and bind it to autoSuggestionsList, or to each <li> but in JS not in PHP.

Comment: Thanks Lolo, really appreciate the help. if I remove the <li> it still does not work. how would I do this in JS and not PHP as you suggest? Thanks again Lolo, apologies for my lack of knowlege.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19777/discussion-between-smudger-and-lolo)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your code is you having same `ID` for all textbox and each `DIV` within for loop

```
<input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
```

It should be unique, like this edit.

```
<input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString<?php echo $i; ?>" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, think you missed the bottom part of my question where I have my updated code. this has a unique id for each input box it the loop. I think some work is needed on the fill() / onblur function to specify which input box to update with the returned values. Thanks again,

Comment: @Smudger yeah you have to change your code for fill() function to get proper textbox ID. That's what is needed.

Comment: Thanks, any advice on how to do that, got me lost?